# pandas - make rows of column 1 as columns and rows of column 2 as values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
A   B
254 1.2
254 0.9
253 2
253 1.8
253 1.9
252 1.5
251 1.2
251 1.7
251 1.8
251 1.6
250 0.9
250 0.95
250 1.1
250 1.11
250 1
```

I need this dataframe to be transformed as:

```
254 253 252 251 250

1.2 2   1.5 1.2 0.9
0.9 1.8     1.7 0.95
    1.9     1.8 1.1
            1.6 1.11
                1
```

Where values 254, 253 etc are now the column names.

I have tried dataframe.T, dataframe.pivot and dataframe.melt techniques but I do not get the desired dataframe as shown above.

Please advise how can this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a helper column and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.assign(index=df.groupby('A').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='index', columns='A', values='B')
   .iloc[:, ::-1]
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
       254  253  252  251   250                        
0      1.2  2.0  1.5  1.2  0.90
1      0.9  1.8  NaN  1.7  0.95
2      NaN  1.9  NaN  1.8  1.10
3      NaN  NaN  NaN  1.6  1.11
4      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.00
```

Or using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) you can pass the index directly:

```
(df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('A').cumcount(), columns='A', values='B')
   .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Comment: second dupe answer.

Comment: I really don't like this reference, there is way too much stuff to be readable, anyway there is a bit more to it than just the pivot

Comment: So check Q/A10 or 11, not sure in first dupe

Comment: or sorting columns

Comment: Sure, I'll add this to be more generic